# Gofiber ctx download []byte file

Tags: go, go-fiber

I am generating files in my backend and keep them in memory.

I want to send the files with the [ctx.Download](https://docs.gofiber.io/api/ctx#download) method but it only accepts a String file path in disk.

How can I trigger a file download like *Download* method sending a []byte file in memory

Comment: Send appropriate Content-Disposition header. (And consider your need for fiber)

Comment: You could have your files stored in tmpfs (memory) and then serve them from there using string filename paths in Download method, just as you would for when the files are stored on disk. Obviously this is unix-specific approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation to what you describe, in that I wanted to download a file from an S3 bucket, but needed a file path for the `Download()` method. So, I wrote the contents of the file downloaded from the S3 bucket to a temporary file, then passed the temporary file's path to the `Download()` method.

Perhaps it's an approach that could work for you as well.

```golang
filename := "file1.txt"

file, err := os.CreateTemp("/tmp/", "temp-*.txt")
if err != nil {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).
        JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": true,
            "msg":   fmt.Sprintf("Couldn't create a temporary file to store the downloaded file. Reason: %v.\n", err),
        })
}
defer os.Remove(file.Name())
    
body, err := io.ReadAll(result.Body)
if err != nil {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).
        JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": true,
            "msg":   fmt.Sprintf("Could not read contents of downloaded file. Reason: %v.\n", err),
        })
}
    
_, err := file.Write(body)
if err != nil {
    return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).
        JSON(fiber.Map{
            "error": true,
            "msg":   fmt.Sprintf("Could not create temporary file with contents of downloaded file. Reason: %v.\n", err),
        })
}
    
return c.Download(file.Name(), filename)
```